# No sound from embedded videos

Tags: bug, ios-app

I have no other sound problems on this phone, but sound doesn’t play in any embedded videos in the SE app. What’s more, it never has. Is this a known issue?

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 6s Plus
- OS Version: Version 11.3 (Build 15E216)

Comment: For whatever reason, the app doesn't have audio for YouTube videos if the ringer is turned off.  If you unsilence the ringer (little switch above the volume buttons) you should get audio.

Comment: That was it, @BrianNickel . Thanks so much!